# How to edit sharepoint 2010 foundation popup dialog menu bar?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, ribbon, editing-menu

How to edit sharepoint 2010 foundation modal window menu bar? e.g. hide "Edit Item" or "Disconfirm" button.

[image: modal window screenshot]

Comment: what do you want to edit?

Comment: can you please elaborate your requirement.?

Comment: I want to hide both of "Edit Item" & "disconfirm" options from the menu. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a custom action on your contenttype..

look at the answer on this thread 
[How can I add button to ribbon that visible only for specific content type?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/57538/how-can-i-add-button-to-ribbon-that-visible-only-for-specific-content-type)